# How To I change Flutter bloc state

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, emit, flutter-state

I am using bloc in my project but when I emit 2 or 3 times the same state my state does not change

```
 on<FetchActivePeriodsEvent>((event, emit) async {
  var model = await _offlineRepository.getPeriods(event.id, event.date);

  final state2 = state as LoadedLocationsState;

  emit(LoadedLocationsState(
      activeAppointments: state2.activeAppointments,
      nameAndSurname: state2.nameAndSurname,
      tc: state2.tc,
      locations: state2.locations,
      activePeriodModel: model.data?.oturumlar??[]));
});
```

How can I emit state with new values